# Aggregate invariants

Tags: domain-driven-design, value-objects

I have doubts about where I should check my invariants...

For example, I have a Question aggregate with the following invariant:

- The question's text must be not null
- The question's text must have a length between 100 and 500 characters

I have read that the best place to check the invariants is in aggregate's constructor, but I have also read it would be recommended push domain logic in value objects, for example.

A possible aggregate's implementation could be:

```
public class Question {
  private final id: QuestionId;
  private final text: QuestionText

  public Question(id: String, text: String) {
    // verify invariants
    ensureLengthText(text); // this method verifies the invariant    

    this.id = new QuestionId(id);
    this.text = new QuestionText(text);
  }
}
```

`QuestionId` and `QuestionText` are value objects.

In this case, in the aggregate we can see the invariant explicitly.

But, if we push that invariant logic in `QuestionText` value object, in the aggregate we will not see that invariant... then, what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can easily enforce an invariant (e.g. "Question texts cannot be shorter than 100 characters nor longer than 500 characters") in a value object, I recommend doing so.  `Question` inherits that invariant (and any and all others from `QuestionText`) by saying that `text` is a `QuestionText`.